# Google app for domain (authentication)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-apps

I'm working on a project, and decided to write a Google App for a Google Apps domain.
I don't know a lot about these things, but I am willing to learn :-)

I created a new application,
set the authentication to users of a specific google apps domain,
uploaded my application with Eclipse,
(my "application" is a html site with javascript),
And I added this application as a service on my Google Apps domain,

But it is still viewable for everyone on the internet...
I know I should do something with the Users Java API, but I don't understand this...
(where should I do that, what should I do?)

Sorry for the beginners-question, but me and my project would be very thankful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use Users API if you want to check user authentication in your code.

OTOH, if you only need to secure some resources (like your html/js/css files, could be static or dynamic) then just configure [security access in deployment descriptor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication), for example, to secure all files in `/static` dir:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I knew it wouldn't be that difficult, but I couldn't find a tutorial for people who don't know a lot about programming etc.